Bluetooth and wifi no longer working after installing GPU drivers
Today I had to install a GPU driver because DaVinci resolve could not open anymore for some reason. However, if it did solve this problem, it somehow messed with my bluetooth and WiFi which don't seem to work anymore (?). Sorry if this is unclear, I am very bad with computers :'( Right now, I can not open the network settings, as they only show "mandatory server". I have no idea what any of this means, please save me.
I don't know how helpful this is but I have a Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060 and my network controller is a mediatek corp device

Can you connect by USB tethering to a smart phone?
